# Why is Prettier making my <br> as a closing tag?

Tags: html, prettier

What is prettier (i Think it is it's fault) changing my `<br>` into `</br>`? How can I deal with it?

before:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vJ3C.jpg)
after: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl3gs.jpg)

I tried to reinstall prettier and change my default formatter but nothing happened.

Comment: Prettier changes the elements and there is no way to disable it because they think that is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Because tags that are not closed, should be self-closed. For example `<br />` and `<img />`

Prettier is doing what is should do.

Comment: should be self-closed is incorrect, its really the linters preference, prettier likes them closed most others like eslint you have options to enable/disable it https://yeonjuan.github.io/html-eslint/docs/rules/require-closing-tags/

Comment: @LawrenceCherone If you want it to be valid XHTML it should be closed, so it's not just preferences. But it's true that it will work without too in browsers.